# In MY_MODEL how to call with() in User defined function in Model (Users_model)

Tags: php, codeigniter, my-model-jami, codeigniter-base-model

I am trying accomplish this.

```
$data['directory_featured'] = $this->Directories_model->with('photos')->get_directory_featured();
```

In that i am trying to call a Photos of the user which are joined using `$has_many` from MY_MODEL . But the next function is written by me. How do i get the photos using the User defined functions in MY_MODEL.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model)

Comment: It is not possible to offer advice when you do not include relevant code.Edit your question and include the `Directories_model` code.

Comment: Ok DFriend. i will add the code.

Comment: class Directories_model extends MY_Model {
    public $table = 'directories';
    public $primary_key = 'id';
    public $fillable = array(); 
    public $protected = array(); 
    public $has_many = array(
        'photos' => array('primary_key' => 'model_id', 'model' => 'Photos_model'),);
public function get_directory_featured() {$query = "";return 0;}

Comment: @DFriend . I have included the Directories_model controller.